# Single word to describe "something that should have been done at the beginning"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word to describe something that should have been done from the beginning to describe the highlighted situation below:

> Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **should be considered from the start** as part of the design.

I know the following is not what I want, but I would like to have a sentence similar to: "Accessibility should be a **first-principles** consideration."

Comment: Check out [synonyms for ***prerequisite***](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/prerequisite). If you want to go really upmarket and impress your work colleagues, consider *...should be a **sine qua non***.

Comment: Why do you want a single word, when it's more effective to spell it out?

Comment: "Accessibility should be anticipated from the get-go." Or, "Accessibility should be endemic, not ad hoc."

Answer (score 3):

A more colloquial term would be "**baked in**" - indicating something that must be there from the start.  (You can't bake a cake, and then add an egg to the batter.  The eggs are baked in, or they aren't there; it's impossible to add one after the fact.)

An *antonym* is "**tacked on**", suggesting something that is added later but not integral to the design.  (Hey.. for that matter, "**integral**" is a good word too.)

> Software should be written with security baked in; it's very difficult to retrofit.

or

> Accessibility should be baked in to the design, not tacked on as an afterthought.

Another possibility is "**foundational**" -- suggesting something that is actually part of the foundation. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundational

> Security is foundational to good software

Comment: I like "baked in" as it conveys the idea that something should be there from the start. To me, the other suggestions such as  "foundational" or "fundamental" convey the idea of importance but not necessarily the idea of "being there from the start". The sentence "accessibility should be a baked-in consideration" make sense, although it seems to read a little awkward.

Comment: I agree "accessibility should be a baked-in consideration" is awkwardly phrased.  I would simply say "Accessibility should be baked in," rather than "a baked in consideration"

Answer (score 1):

**Fundamental** might be one candidate. Referring to the foundations it indicates that anything built upon a shaky start could have bad consequences.

See for example the dictionary entry [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fundamental). An example sentence might be "When casting a bell, the correct preparation of the mould is of **fundamental** importance. If the mould is incorrect, the cast bell will not have the correct sound."

Comment: This could be a good answer, but would need dictionary corroboration (a linked and attributed quote), including an example sentence if possible. The base sense applies to _being_ an essential / core / foundational part of something, rather than a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **should be considered from the start** as part of the design.

You could use a number of words here:

> Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **is required** as part of the design.
>   Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **is a critical** part of the design.
>   Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **is paramount** to the design.
>   Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **is a fundamental** part of the design.
>   Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility **is foundational** as part of the design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the suggestions above are excellent, but since it is important that the accessibility be a part of the design, it really calls for an altered sentence structure.

*Accessibility remediation after the fact is harder. Accessibility should be a design parameter from the start (or "at the conceptual stage").*

Answer (score 0):

> "Accessibility should be **the initial** consideration."

**A.** *adj.* **1.a. Of or pertaining to a beginning; existing at, or constituting, the beginning of some action or process; existing at the outset; primary; sometimes = elementary, rudimentary.**

> After initial consideration of a concern by a relevant member of staff, a student can request a formal investigation by the Head of School/Corporate Service ([Birmingham University](https://intranet.birmingham.ac.uk/student/student-hub/solution.aspx?nodeId=495))

Answer (score -2):

Quintessential -
The beginning is usually the most important.
[image: ss of my answer]

Comment: You should add an explanation of how your suggested words fit the question and include an authoritative dictionary definition.